# How can I find out why java.io.File.mkdir() returns false

Tags: java, file-io

How do I find out why `java.io.File.mkdir()` returns `false`.
I can create the directory manually.

UPDATE:
My code looks like this:

```
String directoryName = "C:/some/path/";
File directory= new File(directoryName );
if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdir()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create directory: " + directoryName);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the directory exists before you try and create it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to use [`mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) if the parent folder (`some` in your example) doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple, you're trying to create nested folders (a folder inside a folder). For nested folders use `File.mkdirs()`. That works, (tested).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, at least not from Java. Being that the OS makes that determination, Java is simply delegating to it and returning the result.

Have you tried ensuring that your File object is pointing where you think it is?

Update: if C:/some does not exist, it must first be created before you can attempt to create C:/some/path. Or use mkdirs() as was pointed out.

Comment: Who said that you can't `mkdir` in java?

Comment: He's saying you can't tell _why_ it failed.

Comment: Quote: `I don't think you can, at least not from Java`. That's not true at all.

Comment: The question was: "How do I find out why java.io.File.mkdir() returns false", so I answered it as, "I don't think you can [find out]"

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) for windows you can view the OS level attempt to create the directory.

That may give you the info you need.

You'll probably need to make use of the filters in process monitor because there's usually a lot of disk activity going on :)

Answer (score 0):

Using **cygwin**?

mkdir may return false, but go on to create the folder anyway.  The false seems only to indicate that the folder does not exist, yet.

You may have to try `directory.exists()` after the `mkdir()` call (or even `mkdirs()`)